# R, a list of data frame, after lapply, the result store also as a list of data frame, how to let the results store in the origin name

Tags: r

R, a list of data frames, after `lapply` some command, the result store also as a list of data frames, but how can I let the results store in each single data frame and use the same name as origin.

for example:
I have 17 data frames, they are all data frames with 100 observations and 50 columns.
I want to drop the 6th column, and store the results into the original name.

The desired output:

before: datanew_V102   100 observations and 50 columns

datanew_V103   100 observations and 50 columns

datanew_V105   100 observations and 50 columns

after:  datanew_V102   100 observations and 49 columns

datanew_V103   100 observations and 49 columns

datanew_V105   100 observations and 49 columns

My code is like:

```
datalist = list(datanewV_102,datanewV_103,datanewV_105,datanewV_107,datanewV_108,datanewV_112,

datanewV_114,datanewV_115,datanewV_118,datanewV_121,datanewV_122,datanewV_126,datanewV_128,

datanewV_183,datanewV_90,datanewV_95,datanewV_99)

remove_col6 <- function(df){
  df[-6]
}
output_list <- lapply(datalist, remove_col6)
```

It gives the output_list as a list of 17 data frames. But if I want to call the first data frame, I need to use `output_list[1]`. How should I assign the original names in `datalist` to the data frame in the `output_list`.

So that, all data frame     with 100 observations and 49 columns
datanewV_102 = output_list[1]

datanewV_103 = output_list[2]

datanewV_105 = output_list[3]

.......

datanewV_114 = output_list[7]

........

datanewV_99 = output_list[17]

How should I write into a single line of code in order to have the above result?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we need to assign the output back to the object, we can use `list2env` (it is not recommended though, because we can do all the transformations within the `list` itself)

```
names(output_list) <- ls(pattern = '^datanewV_\\d+$')
```

Or if the order is important

```
names(output_list) <- c('datanewV_102','datanewV_103','datanewV_105','datanewV_107','datanewV_108','datanewV_112',

 'datanewV_114','datanewV_115','datanewV_118','datanewV_121','datanewV_122','datanewV_126','datanewV_128',

  'datanewV_183','datanewV_90','datanewV_95','datanewV_99')
```

and now use `list2env`

```
list2env(output_list, .GlobaleEnv)
```